# Installation problem of civicrm on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute

Installation problem of civicrm on wordpress : formulaire d'installation

Check the prerequisites and install Civicrm
Reverification of the prerequisites.

Is auto_increment_increment set to 1 Unable to query database server variables.

Is the database name valid? okay

Does the value of MySQL stored procedures (thread_stack) have the required minimum value (192k) Unable to get information about stored procedures in the database.

THANKS FOR YOUR HELP

---

I still have the problem.

Apache 2.4.25 x86 - PHP 7.1.3 x86 Port: 80
  MySQL 5.7.17 x86 Port: 3306
WordPress 5.2.2
CiviCRM-5.16.2-wordpress

On my database.
Privileges are on GRANT in this asso_organization database.

---

Mysql server: localhost
Username Mysql = root
Password = ''
Database = asso_organisation

When I press: check the prerequisites and install CiviCrm:
He created me the database "asso_organisation" but, he always displays two error messages:
Is auto_increment_increment set to 1 /// Unable to query database server variables.
Does the value of MySQL stored procedures (thread_stack) have the required minimum value (192k)? // Unable to get information about the stored procedures of the database.
Thank you for helping me

Comment: Can you check the username and password of mysql user and has permission to run some basic commands on the database

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the mysql user you use doesn't have enough permissions on the database (or invalid database/password?)

This page lists all the privileges that civicrm mysql account needs:

https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/

```
  GRANT
  SELECT,
  INSERT,
  UPDATE,
  DELETE,
  CREATE,
  DROP,
  INDEX,
  ALTER,
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES,
  LOCK TABLES,
  TRIGGER,
  CREATE ROUTINE,
  ALTER ROUTINE,
  REFERENCES,
  CREATE VIEW,
  SHOW VIEW
ON civicrm.*
TO 'civicrm_user'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED BY 'realpasswordhere';
```

you would obviously need to adjust with the database and user account you have